# Headlines Style Without Using Images

Tags: css

Is it possible to achieve the following effect http://www.toastcafebar.com/welcome/ on headlines/titles using only CSS. i.e. The Horizontal Line/Border either side of the Title?

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @LEOPic Webkit, Firefox, ie7 and above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example: http://theleggett.com/explanations/strikethrough/

Solution here: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/comment/43446#Comment_43446

Comment: Ivanic Awesome! Exactly what I'm looking for...